# How to convert this to a file?

Tags: laravel, pdf, decode

I am making a request to an external API, this route should return a PDF file. The problem is that I don't know how to convert the response I'm getting to a PDF file. I'm using Laravel and I wish to convert it to something more readable for the front. Any suggestions?

```
%PDF-1.4
%��͵
1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /PageLayout /SinglePage /PageMode /UseNone /Pages 2 0 R /ViewerPreferences << /NonFullScreenPageMode /UseNone >> >> endobj
2 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Count 3 /Kids [ 16 0 R 22 0 R 28 0 R ] /Resources 3 0 R >> endobj
3 0 obj << /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ] >> endobj
4 0 obj << /Producer (PDF::API2 2.026 [linux]) >> endobj
5 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /TrueType /BaseFont /Verdana,Bold /Encoding << /Type /Encoding /BaseEncoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Differences [ 0 /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /space /exclam /quotedbl /numbersign /dollar /percent /ampersand /quotesingle /parenleft /parenright /asterisk /plus /comma /hyphen /period /slash /zero /one /two /three /four /five /six /seven /eight /nine /colon /semicolon /less /equal /greater /question /at /A /B /C /D /E /F /G /H /I /J /K /L /M /N /O /P /Q /R /S /T /U /V /W /X /Y /Z /bracketleft /backslash /bracketright /asciicircum /underscore /grave /a /b /c /d /e /f /g /h /i /j /k /l /m /n /o /p /q /r /s /t /u /v /w /x /y /z /braceleft /bar /braceright /asciitilde /bullet /Euro /bullet /quotesinglbase /florin /quotedblbase /ellipsis /dagger /daggerdbl /circumflex /perthousand /Scaron /guilsinglleft /OE /bullet /Zcaron /bullet /bullet /quoteleft /quoteright /quotedblleft /quotedblright /bullet /endash /emdash /tilde /trademark /scaron /guilsinglright /oe /bullet /zcaron /Ydieresis /space /exclamdown /cent /sterling /currency /yen /brokenbar /section /dieresis /copyright /ordfeminine /guillemotleft /logicalnot /hyphen /registered /macron /degree /plusminus /twosuperior /threesuperior /acute /mu /paragraph /periodcentered /cedilla /onesuperior /ordmasculine /guillemotright /onequarter /onehalf /threequarters /questiondown /Agrave /Aacute /Acircumflex /Atilde /Adieresis /Aring /AE /Ccedilla /Egrave /Eacute /Ecircumflex /Edieresis /Igrave /Iacute /Icircumflex /Idieresis /Eth /Ntilde /Ograve /Oacute /Ocircumflex /Otilde /Odieresis /multiply /Oslash /Ugrave /Uacute /Ucircumflex /Udieresis /Yacute /Thorn /germandbls /agrave /aacute /acircumflex /atilde /adieresis /aring /ae /ccedilla /egrave /eacute /ecircumflex /edieresis /igrave /iacute /icircumflex /idieresis /eth /ntilde /ograve /oacute /ocircumflex /otilde /odieresis /divide /oslash /ugrave /uacute /ucircumflex /udieresis /yacute /thorn /ydieresis ] >> /FirstChar 32 /FontDescriptor 6 0 R /LastChar 255 /Name /VeBoCDW~1532540977 /Widths [ 341 402 587 867 710 1271 862 332 543 543 710 867 361 479 361 689 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 710 402 402 867 867 867 616 963 776 761 723 830 683 650 811 837 545 555 770 637 947 846 850 732 850 782 710 681 812 763 1128 763 736 691 543 689 543 867 710 710 667 699 588 699 664 422 699 712 341 402 670 341 1058 712 686 699 699 497 593 455 712 649 979 668 650 596 710 543 710 867 710 710 710 332 710 587 1048 710 710 710 1777 710 543 1135 710 691 710 710 332 332 587 587 710 710 1000 710 963 593 543 1067 710 596 736 341 402 710 710 710 710 543 710 710 963 597 849 867 479 963 710 587 867 597 597 710 721 710 361 710 597 597 849 1181 1181 1181 616 776 776 776 776 776 776 1093 723 683 683 683 683 545 545 545 545 830 846 850 850 850 850 850 867 850 812 812 812 812 736 734 712 667 667 667 667 667 667 1018 588 664 664 664 664 341 341 341 341 679 712 686 686 686 686 686 867 686 712 712 712 712 650 699 650 ] >> endobj
6 0 obj << /Type /FontDescriptor /Ascent 1005 /AvgWidth 625 /CapHeight 727 /Descent -209 /Flags 262176 /FontBBox [ -73 -207 1707 1000 ] /FontName /Verdana,Bold /ItalicAngle 0 /MaxWidth 1707 /MissingWidth 300 /StemH 0 /StemV 0 /XHeight 548 >> endobj
7 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /TrueType /BaseFont /Verdana /Encoding << /Type /Encoding /BaseEncoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Differences [ 0 /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /space /exclam /quotedbl /numbersign /dollar /percent /ampersand /quotesingle /parenleft /parenright /asterisk /plus /comma /hyphen /period /slash /zero /one /two /three /four /five /six /seven /eight /nine /colon /semicolon /less /equal /greater /question /at /A /B /C /D /E /F /G /H /I /J /K /L /M /N /O /P /Q /R /S /T /U /V /W /X /Y /Z /bracketleft /backslash /bracketright /asciicircum /underscore /grave /a /b /c /d /e /f /g /h /i /j /k /l /m /n /o /p /q /r /s /t /u /v /w /x /y /z /braceleft /bar /braceright /asciitilde /bullet /Euro /bullet /quotesinglbase /florin /quotedblbase /ellipsis /dagger /daggerdbl /circumflex /perthousand /Scaron /guilsinglleft /OE /bullet /Zcaron /bullet /bullet /quoteleft /quoteright /quotedblleft /quotedblright /bullet /endash /emdash /tilde /trademark /scaron /guilsinglright /oe /bullet /zcaron /Ydieresis /space /exclamdown /cent /sterling /currency /yen /brokenbar /section /dieresis /copyright /ordfeminine /guillemotleft /logicalnot /hyphen /registered /macron /degree /plusminus /twosuperior /threesuperior /acute /mu /paragraph /periodcentered /cedilla /onesuperior /ordmasculine /guillemotright /onequarter /onehalf /threequarters /questiondown /Agrave /Aacute /Acircumflex /Atilde /Adieresis /Aring /AE /Ccedilla /Egrave /Eacute /Ecircumflex /Edieresis /Igrave /Iacute /Icircumflex /Idieresis /Eth /Ntilde /Ograve /Oacute /Ocircumflex /Otilde /Odieresis /multiply /Oslash /Ugrave /Uacute /Ucircumflex /Udieresis /Yacute /Thorn /germandbls /agrave /aacute /acircumflex /atilde /adieresis /aring /ae /ccedilla /egrave /eacute /ecircumflex /edieresis /igrave /iacute /icircumflex /idieresis /eth /ntilde /ograve /oacute /ocircumflex /otilde /odieresis /divide /oslash /ugrave /uacute /ucircumflex /udieresis /yacute /thorn /ydieresis ] >> /FirstChar 32 /FontDescriptor 8 0 R /LastChar 255 /Name /VerdCDX~1532540977 /Widths [ 351 393 458 818 635 1076 726 268 454 454 635 818 363 454 363 454 635 635 635 635 635 635 635 635 635 635 454 454 818 818 818 545 1000 683 685 698 770 632 574 775 751 420 454 692 556 842 748 787 603 787 695 683 616 731 683 988 685 615 685 454 454 454 818 635 635 600 623 520 623 595 351 623 632 274 344 591 274 972 632 606 623 623 426 520 394 632 591 818 591 591 525 634 454 634 818 545 635 545 268 635 458 818 635 635 635 1521 683 454 1069 545 685 545 545 268 268 458 458 545 635 1000 635 976 520 454 981 545 525 615 351 393 635 635 635 635 454 635 635 1000 545 644 818 454 1000 635 541 818 541 541 635 639 635 363 635 541 545 644 1000 1000 1000 545 683 683 683 683 683 683 984 698 632 632 632 632 420 420 420 420 775 748 787 787 787 787 787 818 787 731 731 731 731 615 605 620 600 600 600 600 600 600 955 520 595 595 595 595 274 274 274 274 611 632 606 606 606 606 606 818 606 632 632 632 632 591 623 591 ] >> endobj
8 0 obj << /Type /FontDescriptor /Ascent 1005 /AvgWidth 563 /CapHeight 727 /Descent -209 /Flags 40 /FontBBox [ -49 -206 1446 1000 ] /FontName /Verdana /ItalicAngle 0 /MaxWidth 1446 /MissingWidth 300 /StemH 0 /StemV 0 /XHeight 545 >> endobj
9 0 obj << /Type /XObject /Subtype /Image /BitsPerComponent 1 /ColorSpace [ /Indexed /DeviceRGB 1 10 0 R ] /DecodeParms [ << /BitsPerComponent 1 /Colors 1 /Columns 118 /Predictor 15 >> ] /Filter [ /FlateDecode ] /Height 50 /Length 104 /Name /PxCDY /Width 118 >> stream
(�cX��u�+W'O�)��0��G���:t�~�b�w)����q@�5�Li@�o�RT�
```

Comment: Have you tried open("test.pdf", "w") etc in python?

Comment: Hey @smartse, I forgot to specify that I'm using Laravel

Comment: Show your current code

Comment: Hey, is not code, is a response I am getting when I make a GET request to an URL, the text above is all that is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this when you returns response form a function response should be send like this. I don't know your exact code but i have used this it works properly.

```
$file = 'file.pdf';
$path = storage_path($file);

return Response::make(file_get_contents($path), 200, [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$file.'"'
]);
```